# Install4J XML schema

Tags: xml, xsd, install4j

Good afternoon,
I am a newbie at working with Install4J, and sometimes I wonder whether or not something is feasable or not with the application.
Moreover I already know that automatic updates of the Install4J project might be needed in future.

In order to cover those questions, it would be very useful to have the XML schema of the Install4J source file.
Does anybody know if the XML schema files for Install4J are available somewhere?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no schema for the project file format. Generally it is not recommended to write the project file yourself.

In cases where you need to do so, please observe the changes when you save the project from the IDE.

Comment: We are using ant with a heavily configurable multi-target script and have been manually curating our install4j files for years and with every new release, there's a trial and error run to see how we can use new features.
E.g. right now i tried (and failed) to set the jreBitType from a variable, and have instead to create two media sets and later pick only one file.
A XSD or at least a documentation of the file format would help with that.
That's just one example, please don't solve my problem in the comments.

Comment: I agree that a schema would help. Is there at least a schema for the updates.xml file?

Comment: For the updates.xml file, each entry corresponds to an object that is documented at https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/api/com/install4j/api/update/UpdateDescriptorEntry.html